# wxpython panel shrinks after plot created

Tags: wxpython

I have a very simple panel, where you click a button and a plot is created (using matplotlib) and the plot is saved as a .png in my working folder.

Once the plot is created my panel shrinks in size. Does anyone know why this is?

Below is the code, and then screenshots of before and after the button is clicked.

```
import wx
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(clearSigInt=True)
        self.InitFrame()

    def InitFrame(self):
        frame = MyFrame(parent=None, title='My Frame', pos = (100,100))
        frame.Show()

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title, pos):
        super().__init__(parent=parent, title=title, pos=pos)
        self.OnInit()

    def OnInit(self):
        panel = MyPanel(parent=self)

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        button = wx.Button(parent=self, label = "Create plot", pos = (20,80))
        button.Bind(event=wx.EVT_BUTTON, handler=self.onSubmit)

    def onSubmit(self,event):
        ActivityDF = pd.DataFrame({
            'Activity': ['A','B','C','D'],
            'Count': [10,20,30,40]
        })
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
        ax.barh(ActivityDF['Activity'], ActivityDF['Count'])
        fig.savefig('Figure.png',bbox_inches='tight', facecolor="None")   



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[Before button clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Baa52.png)
[After button clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu2YU.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some code to your question - its much easier to help when we can reproduce the problem in a meaningful way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

First, your code is a little bit overcomplicated. There is no need to use so many classes.

Second, if you plan to use matplotlib with a GUI library then you need to import a backend so matplotlib works fine within the application you are writting.

Regarding why the panel is schrinking. I am not really sure. Perhaps an error when matplotlib tries to plot without the appropiate backend.

I simplified your code and added some comments to it.

```
import wx
import numpy as np

import matplotlib as mpl
## Import the matplotlib backend for wxPython
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

## Only one class is really needed in this case. There is no need to have 
## a class for the App, a class for the frame and a class for the panel
class MyWin(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title, pos):
        super().__init__(parent=None, title=title, pos=pos)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(parent=self)
        self.button = wx.Button(parent=self.panel, label='Create plot', pos=(20, 80))

        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onSubmit)

    def onSubmit(self, event):
        x = np.arange(10)
        y = np.arange(10)
        ## This is to work with matplotlib inside wxPython
        ## I prefer to use the object oriented API
        self.figure  = mpl.figure.Figure(figsize=(5, 5))
        self.axes    = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas  = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        ## This is to avoid showing the plot area. When set to True
        ## clicking the button show the canvas and the canvas covers the button
        ## since the canvas is placed by default in the top left corner of the window
        self.canvas.Show(False)
        self.axes.plot(x, y)
        self.figure.savefig('Figure.png', bbox_inches='tight', facecolor='None')          

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    win = MyWin('My Frame', (100, 100))
    win.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked great thanks! Although, I now want to show the plot, but I would like it to open in a separate window, is there a way to do this?

Comment: @amme. Yes, it is possible. You could, for example, create a new class for the window showing the plot and create a new instance of the plot window using the onSubmit method. Take it step by step. First, learn how to use the onSubmit method to create a new MyWin instance. Then learn how to use the onSubmit method to create a completely different window using a different class, for example, My2Win. And finally, modify My2Win class to show the plot, basically move all the matplotlib code in onSubmit to the My2Win class.

Comment: The problem of the panel shrinking still occurs when using seaborn e.g. import seaborn as sns, sns.boxplot. The plots also save as blank plots. do you know why this is?

Comment: @amme I have never used the seaborn module. If the answer above solved your original problem you should consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. Since I have never used the seaborn module and I cannot help you with this, I think you should ask a new question using a short minimal example. You will have a higher probability of getting an answer this way.